# Lokalise: How to use `include_pids` for specific branch

Tags: translation

I have two projects on [Lokalise](https://lokalise.com/) (the main project and the shared project),
I also use [their API](https://app.lokalise.com/api2docs/curl/#transition-download-files-post) to download the translation files and passing the shared project ID in the `include_pids` to include the shared translation and it works fine.
request body:

```
{
    "format": "json",
    "original_filenames": false,
    "export_empty_as": "skip",
    "include_pids":["641086835fcfa7214a3a83.13574983"]
}
```

Now for some reason, I created a new Branch in the shared project and wanted to get that specific branch, I supposed passing the branch name `FeatureBranchName` would work but it didn't:

```
{
    "format": "json",
    "original_filenames": false,
    "export_empty_as": "skip",
    "include_pids":["641086835fcfa7214a3a83.13574983:FeatureBranchName"]
}
```

does `include_pids` work for specific branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `project_id:branch` schema doesn't work for `include_pids` request parameter at the moment.

You would have to get your branch merged to the default one before using translations from the `FeatureBranchName` branch.